# React Navigation - initial prop when opening via deeplink url

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

As stated in the [react-navigation V5.x docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/): "If you need to render the initial route specified in the navigator, you can disable the behaviour of using the specified screen as the initial screen by setting initial: false:"

`navigation.navigate('Root', { screen: 'Settings', initial: false, });`

So, are there any best practices for handling a url like `myapp://root/settings` with a `path` in such a case.. let's say this url is opening your app via push or some other external source. URL is handled with `Linking.openURL(url).catch();`

What if the `Settings` screen is not the root/initial screen of the stack, but maybe `Feed`-> So the back button on `Settings` will direct somewhere else (or nowhere).

Is there a better approach besides hacking this inside `onReceiveURL()` with checking if the initial screen exists on the Stack? Am I conceptually completely missing something here?

** imo: there should also be a better approach for this bedsides using the `lazy={false}` prop

---

#### UPDATE:

You'll need to set an `initialRouteName` not only on the stack navigator itself but also accordingly on your Linking config.. this was missing for me:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/configuring-links#rendering-an-initial-route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set an initialRouteName not only on the stack navigator itself but also accordingly on your Linking config.. this was missing for me:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/configuring-links#rendering-an-initial-route